# Configure SABRE SOAP API

Tags: asp.net, sabre

I want to build a travel portal using sabre soap api. But soap api credential is not found in my account section of developer site(https://developer.sabre.com). I have submitted contact us page several times to get the credential. But there is no reply from sabre. Can anyone please help me to get the credential of sabre soap api?

Comment: Hit me up. I have an IATA, I'll be your ticket issuer. Seriously though, I found that I had to ask our account rep to get authorized credentials, which is not the way to do it. Even then, getting the additional permissions, I had to ask like 3 times. Talking to a travel agent first might be a good idea if only because they would have a better point of contact then you.

Answer (score 0):

The setup process usually goes getting access to the Sabre GUI (Sabre Red Workspace) and then getting access to the APIs. So i would try this route.

Other way to go is to contact your (future) ticket issuer/consolidator if you are not an IATA Office/number holder yourself.